# LLVM pass to count vector type instructions

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to write an LLVM pass that counts instructions of vector type.
for instructions like :

```
  %24 = or <2 x i64> %21, %23
  %25 = bitcast <16 x i8> %12 to <8 x i16>
  %26 = shl <8 x i16> %25, <i16 1, i16 1, i16 1, i16 1, i16 1, i16 1, i16 1, i16 1>
  %27 = bitcast <8 x i16> %26 to <2 x i64>
```

I wrote this code:

```
for (auto &F : M) {      
    for (auto &B : F) {
            for (auto &I : B) {

            if (auto* VI = dyn_cast<InsertElementInst>(&I)) {
                     Value* op = VI->getOperand(0);
                     if (op->getType()->isVectorTy()){
                         ++vcount;
                     }

            }
```

But for some reason `if (auto* VI = dyn_cast<InsertElementInst>(&I))` is never satisfied.
Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`InsertElementInst` is one specific instruction (that inserts an element into a vector) - and there is none in your list of instructiokns.

You probably want to <strike>`dyn_cast` to a regular</strike> use the [`Instruction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) in `I` as it is.

[I personally would use a one of the function or module pass classes as a base, so you only need to implement the inner loops of your code, but that's more of a "it's how you're supposed to do things", not something you HAVE to do to make it work].

Comment: You wouldn't need to `dyn_cast` at all, since `I` would already be an `Instruction&` here.

Comment: @Ismail: So amended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand how I would count instructions that return a vector type by just using the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

In LLVM, the instruction *is* the same as it's result. so for an example

```
%25 = bitcast <16 x i8> %12 to <8 x i16>
```

when you cast Instruction I to value you get %25

```
Value* psVal = cast<Value>(&I);
```

and then you can check if it is of vector type or not by getType()->isVectorTy().

Also i suggest you look at inheritance diagram of llvm Value for more clarification

here http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.